# Xcode gets stuck on "Copying media to the package" when uploading archive to App Store

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect

As the title says. After I archive the project and try to upload to the App Store, Xcode gets stuck while uploading. It's been several hours now and the progress bar hasn't moved at all. My internet is working correctly. My app has a few pictures in the assets folder, which I assume is the media the loading message refers to.

Answer (score 0):

you can try uploading with Applictaion Loader,might be there is some issue with apple server.